derivation of a third-order normal component tensor of a fourth-order tensor
I have the following constitutive material fourth-order tensor $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{C}}$
\begin{equation}
      \boldsymbol{\mathcal{C}}= \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{P}}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}, \quad
       \mathcal{C}_{iIjJ} =  \frac{\partial {P}_{iI}}{\partial{F}_{jJ}} 
\end{equation}
My question is related to the third-order normal component tensor $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{C}}_N$:
\begin{equation}
      \boldsymbol{\mathcal{C}}_N= \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{N}}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}, \quad
       \mathcal{C}_{ijJ} =  \frac{\partial {P}_{iI}}{\partial{F}_{jJ}} N_I 
\end{equation}
where  $\boldsymbol{N}$ is a unit normal vector, and $\boldsymbol{P}$ is piola-kirchhoff stress tensor given by:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{P}(\boldsymbol{F})=\mu J^{-2/3}\left[\boldsymbol{F}-\frac{1}{3}(\boldsymbol{F}:\boldsymbol{F})\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\right]+\kappa(J-1)J\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}
\end{equation}
now, evaluation of $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{C}}$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}&\mathcal{C}(\boldsymbol{F})=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{P}}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}=-\frac{2}{3}\mu J^{-2/3}\boldsymbol{F}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}+\frac{2}{9}\mu J^{-2/3}(\boldsymbol{F}:\boldsymbol{F})\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\\&+\mu J^{-2/3}\boldsymbol{\mathcal{I}}-\frac{1}{3}\mu J^{-2/3}(\boldsymbol{F}:\boldsymbol{F})\mathcal{H}-\frac{2}{3}\mu J^{-2/3}\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}\\&+\kappa J(2J-1)\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}+\kappa J(J-1)\boldsymbol{H}.\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
here,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H} = \partial\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}/\partial\boldsymbol{F} = -F_{iJ}^{-T}F_{jI}^{-T},\quad \partial J/\partial\boldsymbol{F} = J\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}, \quad \boldsymbol{\mathcal{I}} = \delta_{ij}\delta_{jJ}.
\end{equation}
I tried to go through to evaluate $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{C}}_{N}$, but due to the lack of experience with tensor algebra, it is hard for me to verify my answer, which reads,
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\left[\mathcal{C}_{ N}\right]_{ijJ}=\mathcal{C}_{i I j I} N_I=} & \alpha_1\, F_{iI}F^{-T}_{jJ} \,N_I+\alpha_2 F^{-T}_{iI}F^{-T}_{jJ}\,N_I \\
& +\alpha_3\, \mathcal{I}_{iIjJ} \,N_I+\alpha_4 F^{-T}_{iJ}F^{-T}_{jI} \,N_I-\alpha_5\, F^{-T}_{iI}F_{jJ} \,N_I \\
& +\alpha_6\, F^{-T}_{iI}F^{-T}_{jJ} \,N_I-\alpha_7\, F^{-T}_{iJ}F^{-T}_{jI}\,N_I .
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\alpha_i \,; i=1..6$  are constants.  Defining $\boldsymbol{F}^{-T} \boldsymbol{N} = \boldsymbol{m}$, and $\boldsymbol{F}^{-T} \boldsymbol{N} = \boldsymbol{m}^{\star}$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\mathcal{C}_N=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{P}\boldsymbol{N}}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}&=
\alpha_1\,\boldsymbol{m}^{\star}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}+
\alpha_2\,\boldsymbol{m}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\\&+
\alpha_3\,\boldsymbol{\mathcal{I}_N}-
\alpha_4\,\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{m} -
\alpha_5\,\boldsymbol{m}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}\\&+
\alpha_6\,\boldsymbol{m}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}+
\alpha_7\,\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{m}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
To wrap up my question, I want to know how to do the following operations:
\begin{aligned}
(\boldsymbol{F} \otimes \boldsymbol{F}^{-T})(\boldsymbol{N}) &= F_{iI}F^{-T}_{jJ} \,N_I &= \boldsymbol{m}^{\star}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\\
(\boldsymbol{F}^{-T} \otimes \boldsymbol{F})(\boldsymbol{N}) &= F^{-T}_{iI}F_{jJ} \,N_I &= \boldsymbol{m}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}\\
(\boldsymbol{F}^{-T} \otimes \boldsymbol{F}{-T})(\boldsymbol{N}) &= F^{-T}_{iI}F^{-T}_{jJ} \,N_I &= \boldsymbol{m}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\\
\mathcal{H} = (\partial\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}/\partial\boldsymbol{F})(\boldsymbol{N}) &= -F_{iJ}^{-T}F_{jI}^{-T} N_I &=\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{m}
\end{aligned}
Please let me know if you find anything wrong with my derivation.
I have another question related to groping terms together. My final goal is to arrive at a simplified form of the tensor such that I can find its eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and nullspace.
Thank you and best regards.
